# incomplete ifnum

Tags: hyperref, conditionals, enumerate, loops, xkeyval

I am using a loop to define keys with the `xkeyval` package, as well as to actually read out the keys inside some self-defined command. Everything works perfectly - but for some reason, as soon as I include `hyperref`, everything breaks:

```
! Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line 47.
<inserted text> 
            \fi
```

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{hyperref} % <-- comment this line to make it work

\makeatletter

\count@=0
\loop
  \advance\count@ 1
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\define@key{mycmd}{KEY\the\count@}[]{%
      \noexpand\@namedef{mycmdKEY\the\count@}{####1}%
    }% end of \define@key
  }% end of \edef
  \x % execute \x
\ifnum\count@<6
\repeat
\presetkeys{mycmd}{KEY1=0,KEY2=0,KEY3=0,KEY4=0,KEY5=0,KEY6=0,%
}{}

\newcount\mycount%
\newcounter{mycnt}

\newcommand*\mycmd[2][]{%
\setkeys{mycmd}{#1}{
  \begin{enumerate}
  \mycount=0%
  \loop%
  \advance\mycount 1%
  \setcounter{mycnt}{\csname mycmdKEY\the\mycount\endcsname}%
  \ifnum\value{mycnt}>0%
    \item[item \the\mycount] text
  \fi%
  \ifnum\mycount<6\repeat%
  \end{enumerate}
}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mycmd[
  KEY1=200,
  KEY2=200,
  KEY3=500,
  KEY4=1000,
]{}

\end{document}
```

Here are my observations:

- If I remove the dependency on `hyperref`, it works.
- If I remove the `enumerate` environment and replace the call to `\item` with its argument, it also works.
- If I remove the call to `setkeys` and replace the string `\csname mycmdKEY\the\mycount\endcsname` with `1`, it also works.

All of this seems pretty weird to me. If anybody could tell me what I am doing wrong here and what I can do to fix it, that would be great!

PS: If you are wondering how I came up with this code in the first place: 
This question is a follow-up issue based on an earlier question of mine: [Defining xkeyval keys within a loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206791/defining-xkeyval-keys-within-a-loop)

Comment: hyperref redefines \item.  However, to fix it all you need is to use \ifnum\value{mycnt}>0\relax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several bad `%` in your code. Always leave a space after a constant (or add `\relax`. In particular the bad one is at

```
\ifnum\value{mycnt}>0%
  \item[item \the\mycount] text
\fi%
```

When TeX wants to perform this check, it expands `\item` to see if some more digits come along. In the case `hyperref` is loaded, the first level expansion of `\item` is

```
\@hyper@itemfalse\if@nmbrlist\@hyper@itemtrue\fi\H@item
```

but TeX doesn't stop expanding and finds

```
\let\if@hyper@item\iffalse
```

which adds *two* conditionals in the input stream. At this point, though, TeX determines that the number is actually zero. If `mycnt` is bigger than zero, `\let\if@hyper@item\iffalse` becomes part of the false text, and the `\fi` is matched with `\iffalse`, leaving `\ifnum` unfinished.

Correct code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\count@=0
\loop
  \advance\count@ 1
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\define@key{mycmd}{KEY\the\count@}[]{%
      \noexpand\@namedef{mycmdKEY\the\count@}{####1}%
    }% end of \define@key
  }% end of \edef
  \x % execute \x
\ifnum\count@<6
\repeat
\presetkeys{mycmd}{KEY1=0,KEY2=0,KEY3=0,KEY4=0,KEY5=0,KEY6=0,%
}{}

\newcount\mycount%
\newcounter{mycnt}

\newcommand*\mycmd[2][]{%
\setkeys{mycmd}{#1}{%
  \begin{enumerate}
  \mycount=0
  \loop
  \advance\mycount 1
  \setcounter{mycnt}{\csname mycmdKEY\the\mycount\endcsname}%
  \ifnum\value{mycnt}>0
    \item[item \the\mycount] text
  \fi
  \ifnum\mycount<6
  \repeat
  \end{enumerate}
}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mycmd[
  KEY1=200,
  KEY2=200,
  KEY3=500,
  KEY4=1000,
]{}

\end{document}
```

See [Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19922/where-are-the-necessary-places-to-be-appended-with-to-remove-unwanted-spaces) and [When is it harmful to add percent character at end of lines in a \newcommand, or similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34844/when-is-it-harmful-to-add-percent-character-at-end-of-lines-in-a-newcommand-or)