# textbf is bolding all following text beyond the bracket closure

Tags: macros, luatex, bold

I have a series of .tex files that are being compiled by lualatex, and this particular .tex file is making Title 4 and all the text in the following .tex files appear bolded after compilation even though they don't have a preceding \textbf or \bf. My assumption was that I was missing a bracket close, but it doesn't appear that way, so I tried removing the very first \textbf so the line reads:

```
\hspace{1cm}\large{Title 1, \foo}
```

This broke everything though, and gave me this error:
"! Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line 293."
I was able to remove the \textbf from the Title 3 line that did *not* invoke the *foo* function though, so my thought was that the problem lies in that function.

A quick google brought me [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208006/incomplete-ifnum), but I tried playing around with the %s that I had in my function and couldn't figure out how to make it compile or fix the bolding issue.

I'm really stuck on this and would greatly appreciate any advice!! Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\insertquarter}{%
  Q%
  \ifcase\month\or4\or1\or1\or1\or2\or2\or2\or3\or3\or3\or4\or4\fi
}

\newcommand{\lastMonthAlternate}{\ifcase \month\or %
December \or January\or February\or March\or %
April\or May \or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\fi \hspace{1mm}\number \numexpr\year\ifnum\month=1 -1\fi\relax}

\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \ifnum\month=1
    \insertquarter\ \number\numexpr\year-3\relax\ -- \insertquarter\ \number\numexpr\year-1\relax 
  \else%
    \ifnum\month\or4\or7\or10
      \insertquarter\ \number\numexpr\year-2\relax\ -- \insertquarter\ \number\year
    \else%
      \insertquarter\ \number\numexpr\year-2\relax\ -- \lastMonthAlternate
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\hspace{1cm}\large\textbf{Title 1, \foo}

\hspace{1cm}\large\textbf{Title 2, \foo}

\hspace{1cm}\large\textbf{Title 3}

\hspace{1cm}\large{Title 4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Can you condense your example into a small compilable document that shows the problem? For example, we have no access to your graphics files, and they're presumably irrelevant to the problem you're having, so remove that code, etc.

Comment: The most likely source of this problem is an instance of `\bfseries` rather than `\textbf` unless you've got a really misplaced closing `}`.

Comment: My apologies. it should compile now.

Comment: `\bfseries doesn't appear in any other documents however, and if you try compiling the above code you can see that Title 4 is bolded, but if you delete Titles 1-3, it's not bolded.

Comment: Yes, I see that now! It wasn't clear before the complete example was available. :)

Comment: Please don't cross-post on multiple sites without disclosing all versions of your post in each version.

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/75008345/2777074

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to use your `\foo` macro outside of the `\textbf` you can see that you get an error `Incomplete \ifnum`.  This shows that your `\foo` macro doesn't actually work the way you want it too, because you have a missing `\fi`.  If we add that `\fi` to the macro then your document works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\insertquarter}{%
  Q%
  \ifcase\month\or4\or1\or1\or1\or2\or2\or2\or3\or3\or3\or4\or4\fi
}

\newcommand{\lastMonthAlternate}{\ifcase \month\or %
December \or January\or February\or March\or %
April\or May \or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\fi \hspace{1mm}\number \numexpr\year\ifnum\month=1 -1\fi\relax}

\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \ifnum\month=1
    \insertquarter\ \number\numexpr\year-3\relax\ -- \insertquarter\ \number\numexpr\year-1\relax 
  \else%
    \ifnum\month\or4\or7\or10
      \insertquarter\ \number\numexpr\year-2\relax\ -- \insertquarter\ \number\year
    \else%
      \insertquarter\ \number\numexpr\year-2\relax\ -- \lastMonthAlternate
  \fi
\fi%
}

\begin{document}

\hspace{1cm}\large\textbf{Title 1,\foo }

\hspace{1cm}\large{Title 4}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]